# What is the need of 'if statement' in this python code?

Tags: python

Even if I remove the 'if statement' from the code,I get the same output.

```
   word='pizza'
   begin=None
   while begin!='':
         begin=(raw_input('\nBegin:'))
         if begin:
             begin=int(begin)
             end = int(raw_input('End:'))
             print "word[",begin,":",end,"]"
             print word[begin:end]
   raw_input("\n\nPress enter key")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if the user entered something other than the empty string.

```
>>> if '':
...     print 'empty'
...
>>> if 'I entered something':
...     print 'not empty'
...
not empty
>>> raw_input('just hit enter: ')  # just hinting 'enter' results in the empty string
just hit enter:
''
```

Comment: It can't be. Because, the input should not be a empty string.

Comment: @GobinathEm: That is what it is testing for; the input *can* be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The if is used to make sure that the input of `begin=(raw_input('\nBegin:'))` is not empty. In [pep 08](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), in "Programming Recommendations" section you can see that:

"For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false."

Comment: Yeah. I got it. Thanks.
But where does the if statement checks that if the input in null?
I mean, where is the Condition for if statement?

Comment: the condition is equivalent to `if x is not None` or `if len(x)==0`, i updated my answer.

Comment: Okay. So,in python, we don't have to include a condition to check 'true' or 'false'?

Comment: Normally you write a 'full' condition, but in some cases like this one you don't need to write the conventional 'full' expression to check for emptiness.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` checks if the user just pressed `Enter`.

If you remove the `if`, execute the program and just press `Enter`, you will see the output like this:

```
Begin:


Press enter key
```

If you enter `1` and press `Enter`, the output will be this:

```
Begin:1Begin:


Press enter key
```

Comment: If I remove `if` the program does not accepts a null input.
So,it just checks that if the input is empty or not.